# Gurobi: Get optimization runtime

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, gurobi

I would like to access the **time** it took to find the optimal solution of model `m` when running a mathematical optimization problem in gurobi from python.

So far I use

```
runtime = m.Runtime
print("The run time is %f" % runtime)
```

Unfortunately, the returned runtime is always 0.0, independent of the time it took to solve the model, and before any timelimit is reached.

```
    m.setParam("TimeLimit", timeLimit)
```

How can the actual runtime be accessed in gurobi via gurobipy? I have read the [Gurobi reference manual](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/5.6/reference-manual/runtime) but without success.

Comment: As in the answer in [this link](https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360043084272-Why-is-the-Runtime-attribute-0-) mentioned, you should query the Runtime attribute immediately after `model.optimize()` call to get the correct runtime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just tried adding the following line to the assignment.py example file, and it seemed to print out the runtime just fine.

```
print m.Runtime
```

Are you sure you're calling it after m.optimize() but before calling m.update() or anything else that resets the model run time? Try printing the run time immediately after m.optimize().

EDIT: I just realized that the assignment.py was one of mine, not the example problem.

```
from gurobipy import *
from numpy import *

numT = 300;
numC = 300;

Assignment = random.random((numT,numC))

m=Model("Assignment")

X = []
for t in range(numT):
    X.append([])
    for c in range(numC):
        X[t].append(m.addVar(vtype=GRB.BINARY,name="X%d%d"% (t, c)))
m.update()
m.modelSense = GRB.MAXIMIZE
constraintT = []
constraintC = []
for t in range(numT):
    constraintT.append(m.addConstr(quicksum(X[t][c] for c in range(numC)) == 1 ,'constraintT%d' % t))

for c in range(numC):
    constraintT.append(m.addConstr(quicksum(X[t][c] for t in range(numT)) == 1 ,'constraintC%d' % t))

m.setObjective(quicksum(quicksum([X[t][c]*Assignment[t][c] for c in range(numC)]) for t in range(numT)))

m.update()
m.optimize()

print 'runtime is',m.Runtime
```

Comment: Thanks @brugaltheelder. With your help I can now access the runtime. The problem was that I accessed `m` after performing `m.update()`. Now I'm doing this before, and I can easily access the runtime.